# Qlikview - show min and max date from date listbox

Tags: date, max, min, qlikview

I have ListBox with value day(Date) and shows results:

1
2
3
4
5
6
7

I want when select number from 2 to 5 in table get result

```
Date from       Date To
02-02-2022      05-02-2022
```

Can anyone help me please, how to show first and last selected value from list box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it in 2 text boxes of the form

```
='Date from'&chr(15)&
  date(min(Date),'DD-MM-YYYY')
```

chr(15) is to create a new line. Just switch out the min() for max() as needed

Comment: Great, it works! Thanks!